# Laptop not powering down when lid is closed, but when lid is opened

Tags: windows-vista, laptop, power-management

Currently when I close the lid of my Acer laptop running Windows Vista, the laptop does not power down; however, when I open the lid it does. When looking at the power settings it is set to power down when closing the lid. The trigger to this seems to be the lid being opened not being closed.

I seem to recall this behaviour changing when I installed Windows Media centre.

Any ideas on how I can get the power down to work on the lid closing?

Thanks.

Comment: Has there been any damage to the computer's screen/lid area? I have an old Dell which I've dropped a few times, and that messed up the trigger switch for detecting whether the lid is closed or not. Because of this, it only seems to detect that the lid is "closed" when it is being opened past a certain point.

Comment: My wife had a laptop that would sleep when she closed the lid. If she used the windows menu to manually shut down and then closed the lid, the laptop would begin to shut down and then sleep. When she next opened the lid, the laptop would wake, then finish the shutdown process. This sounds similar to what you are experiencing.

Comment: Hi Benbun, did you ever resolve this? I have an Acer v3-771g that has the same pesky  behaviour: all power modes are set to sleep on closing the lid but it does nothing at all..

Answer (score 0):

Is it set to power down on lid closing on both battery and cord power?

Comment: Yes battery and cord power settings are the same, they are set to "Shut Down"

When I close the lid the laptop remains powered up, it's only when I open the lid again that the "power down" process starts.

Comment: Check if there's a (BIOS) setting that puts the computer to a hardware sleep, halting and suspending all processes. That would suspend the power down until the point all operations are resumed.

Answer (score 0):

YOu'll have to look and edit in each power setting, balanced, high preformance and power saving and pick the settings there that work best. It has actions for the lid, what to do on close on plugged in and what to do on batter. To fully set this up how you want it, you'll need to set it at least 6 times (3 power modes, on each of them, for battery and plugged in)

Media center could have done it, because it will let you keep a computer on (prevent sleep, shutdown, etc) while media is sharing, including the ability to allow a sleeping computer to be waken up to share media. My bet is media center changed 2 settings, the What do do what the lib closes, and maybe even the media sharing. Look into them both.