# Windows 10 not automatically shutting down

Tags: windows-10, laptop, shutdown, lenovo-laptop

I have a Windows 10 Lenovo laptop that, after being closed, will go into sleep mode for about 8 hours and then is supposedly supposed to shut down. However, it does not do this; after 8 hours, it exits sleep mode and turns on with the screen closed. It does not go back to sleep mode after this, it just stays on; this makes the laptop very hot for hours on end, which I'm sure cannot be good for it. There is no common application open that I can tell that would cause this, so it must be something in the background or a setting. It does have a Windows 10 "When would you like to update?" message occasionally when this happens.

In the Control Panel > Power Options, "Choose what closing the lid does" is set to sleep. I'm aware of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/477245/why-laptops-sometimes-not-shutting-down-when-lid-closed-red-hot-laptop-from-bag?rq=1) question which suggests setting this to shutdown or the powerbutton to shutdown, but this would make the laptop troublesome to use as it needs to be transported frequently.

How can I make a Windows 10 Lenovo laptop (Yoga 910) automatically shut down after being asleep for ~8 hours?

Comment: It is likely something is waking it up, such as windows updates. `powercfg /lastwake` should tell you what woke up the laptop last time. If you close the lid and the next day it is turned on, execute that command to learn more.

Comment: @LPChip Thanks, I'll try running that the next time this happens. I'll post an update if it reveals anything.