# Asleep laptop running and hot in backpack, any brand, any OS

Tags: laptop, sleep

I put my laptop to sleep, waited until fans were off, closed lid, put it in backpack, opened my backpack later, laptop was running and hot, fans on. I opened the lid, the screen stays black forever with laptop fans running, no way to get it back to work other than pressing the on/off button for 10 seconds to force a hard reboot.

(Note: this question is not an exact duplicate of [Why Laptops sometimes not shutting down when Lid closed? Red-hot laptop from bag, why?](https://superuser.com/questions/477245) because I only close the lid at the third step whereas in that post, the person first starts by closing the lid.)

This happens to me once in a while. According to the Internet, this happens to many people too. What I don't understand is that I had this problem or a variant of this problem with many different configurations: 15 years ago with a Mac laptop, with a Dell PC on Windows 5 years later, then with another Macbook, at least once with a Gigabyte PC on Windows, and today with a Dell PC on Linux (Ubuntu).

Is this problem so hard to fix? What is its origin anyway? Obviously not the OS since it concerns the main 3 ones.

Comment: It is easy to fix. Close the lid to put to sleep and then verify asleep (outside light to indicate). Do not close the lid after it is asleep as closing the lid wakes it up. I carry suspended laptops regularly in my briefcase without issue.

Comment: Thanks. From my pas experience I had the impression closing the lid directly is even worse, but I'll give it a try again for a while and see.

Comment: Should not be. Closing the lid to suspend is what I have done for many years. Always works.  Just set the Power and Lid properties correctly